Why are deprecated elevation-based tint overlays still in Material Design 3 Component Specs page?
I'm using --md-sys-color-surface-container-low as my Card surface color, then I referred to Material 3's Card Component Specs page , and it says one of the specs is Elevated card container surface tint layer color md.sys.color.surface-tint
I referred to it just to check if I did the specs right, but I also know that tint feature has been deprecated:
Introducing Tone-based Surfaces in Material 3
Deprecated - Surface tint overlays
So now I'm confused, because I do feel like the color on my app is off, and yet I don't know if I should implement the now-deprecated tint system.
I'm not using the deprecated tint system, but I'm unsure if it's the cause of the color issue in my app.

Deprecated classes are not meant to be used in new code, and are usually slated for removal in a later version. In fact, the page you linked mentions this explicitly:

Material Design no longer supports those overlays, and they should not be used in combination with the new surface color roles.

Tone-based surfaces are in fact the new way to go.

Thanks for clarification, but my problem is, in the specs page, they list the tint along with the tone based surface, making it as if it's still the official spec. so they haven't updated it yet or is it intentional?
and in addition, if you use the material theme builder, the css genereated still have --md-sys-color-surface-tint

@zircon98 Just Google being themselves tbh - They've probably deprecated it in one place and haven't gotten to updating it elsewhere. Honestly if this app is for a school project or something and it's easier to use the deprecated way then do that but I wouldn't use it for anything meant to be maintained long-term
